# Duplicating a movie strip in the VSE

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I want to duplicate the active strip and place the duplicate strip in the next available channel above the original.

I have been doing this manually by shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then dragging the strip manually above.  The code behind <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is:

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate_move(SEQUENCER_OT_duplicate={"mode":'TRANSLATION'},
TRANSFORM_OT_seq_slide={"value":(0, 0), "snap":False,
"snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False,
"snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "release_confirm":False})
```

In this code how do I specify to move up by one channel the duplicated movie strip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the info panel when you <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you do get that python there, but that only duplicates the strip and snaps it to the end of the first strip. If you move it to above the existing strip, it also uses `bpy.ops.transform.seq_slide(value=(-26,1))` where `-26` is to move the strip the number of frames of the strip(original is 26 frames) and the `1` is positive direction next channel. If you automate it, you will need to have the python look get the number of frames of the strip and use that where the `-26` is.

Comment: Thanks Craig, just the job, I'm lovin this scripting thing!